# Template deduction for std::function

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I have the following code:

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T, std::vector<T>){}

template<typename T>
void bar(T, std::function<void(T)>){}

int main()
{
    foo(0, std::vector<int>{});
    bar<int>(0, [](int){});
}
```

`foo` can work without explicitly specifying the template type, and `bar` does not work if I do not specify the type like:

```
bar(0, [](int){});  //Compile error: no matching function for call to 'bar(main()::<lambda(int)>)'
```

1. Why does the template deduction works for foo but not bar? How can I make it work? I do not want to template the whole type of function because I wanna make sure the function takes the parameter type T, the same as the first parameter.
2. Since template type T can be deducted from the first parameter, can I do something like: `foo(0, std::vector<auto>{});` (I understand it does not compile). Any workaround?

Comment: A lambda isn't a `std::function`, and it won't deduce as one.

Comment: However, there is a very simple workaround (deduction suppression for the 2nd param), and this can be an answer here - so it's not full duplicate.